# Upstream filtering a users AD users group membership list by wild-carded string

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have a requirement to combine Get-ADUser and Get-ADGroup (with filtering) to retrieve a list of a users groups, only where the group name matches a wildcard pattern I specify.

Getting the whole list of a users groups can be slow over VPN when WFH. So instead of retrieving *all* the users group names into an array, then looping through that to find the matching names I need, can I include the group name filtering further upstream in the Get-ADUser call, or the Get-ADGroup call?

My question isn't so much "how is it done?" but "can it be done?", and would it actually be any quicker than pulling *all* group names into an array then looping.

Something like:

```
$SEC_GROUPS = (Get-ADUser $_ –Properties MemberOf).memberof | 
Get-ADGroup -filter {Name -like "*SEC*"} -Properties Name,Description |
Select-Object Name,Description |
Sort-Object name
```

Thank you for any replies so far

I had another bash and thought this worked:

```
$SEC_GROUPS = (get-aduser $_ -properties Memberof).memberof |
Get-ADGroup -filter 'Name -like "*SEC*"' -Properties Name,Description -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |
select-object Name,Description |
Sort-Object Name
```

But it pulls **all** matching AD groups, not just those the user is a member of.

**Update:** Using the comment from Santiago below was the trick. Remember, for speed I needed to retrieve *only* the user groups matching the group name pattern I specify, as early as possible, no manually processing on the full groups list.

> ```
> $SEC_GROUPS = (get-aduser $_ -properties Memberof).memberof -like '*SEC*' |
> Get-ADGroup -Properties Name,Description |
> select-object Name,Description |
> Sort-Object Name
> ```

I found that, even when my group names started with SEC I still needed to include the * on both side of the match pattern, using SEC* didn`t work. I'm guessing this is because the match target starts with CN=SEC_*whatever*

Comment: Use following to debug : $groupsLIST = (Get-ADUser $tbv –Properties MemberOf).memberof | Get-ADGroup -Properties Name,Description | Format-Table  OR $groupsLIST = (Get-ADUser $tbv –Properties MemberOf).memberof | Get-ADGroup -Properties Name,Description | Foreach {$_ | format-Table}

Comment: Why not do the filtering over the group's DN: `(Get-ADUser $_ –Properties MemberOf).memberof -notlike '*SEC*'` ?

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon - Thank you for your comment, exactly what was needed, as 'upstream' as possible = 'fast'. Not retrieving all the users groups in the first place! Please add your comment as an answer so I can accept it (I know you probably will later anyway). Legend.

Comment: My answer is already there

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Active Directory Filter to search for all groups having your user as `member` and having a `name` containing `SEC`. This is as fast as it gets in my opinion.

```bash
$user   = (Get-ADUser someUser).DistinguishedName
$groups = Get-ADGroup -LDAPFilter "(&(member=$user)(name=*SEC*))" -Properties Description |
    Select-Object Name, Description |
    Sort-Object Name
```

If you want to give it a try you can also filter the `memberof` property of your user including those having a `CN` (common name) containing `SEC` (I don't think this will be faster or more robust than before snippet):

```bash
$groups = (Get-ADUser someUser -Properties memberOf).memberOf -match '(?<=^CN=).*SEC.*?(?<!\\),' |
    Get-ADGroup -Properties Description |
    Select-Object Name, Description |
    Sort-Object Name
```

Comment: I thought the -LDAPfilter approach would need to iterate over all AD groups, to check if the user was a member, but I guess this is another case where Powershell knows all the shortcuts and efficiencies.

Comment: @Doofus it's not powershell the one that knows, it's Active Directory. This kind of filtering is directly done by AD (pwsh has nothing to do with it) hence this should be faster